# Magento 2 Mage::reset() equivalent

Tags: magento2, reset

There is a Mage::reset() equivalent in Magento 2?

**EDIT**

The problem is:

I created a cli command that will create file to upload ebay listing...
Here I got a foreach loop:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $this->_state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
    $areaObject = $this->_areaList->getArea(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
    $areaObject->load(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::PART_TRANSLATE);
----
    foreach ($input->getOption(self::C_EBAY_STORES) as $ebaystore){
        foreach ($input->getOption(self::C_EBAY_SITES) as $site){

            $locale = $this->_helper->getLocale($site);
            $this->_storeManagerInterface->setCurrentStore($locale['store']);
            $this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($locale['currency']);
            $this->_coreSession->setCountryCode($locale['iso']);
            $this->_emulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($this->_storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getCode(), 'frontend');

            
            $collection = $this->getCollection($this->_helper->getEbayAttribute($ebaystore,$site));
            foreach($collection as $product){
                if($product->isSaleable()){
                    
                    if(!in_array($product->getId(),$syncIds)){
                        $syncIds[] = $product->getId();
                    }
                    
                    $product->load($product->getId());              
            
                    $output->writeln("\t\t<info>SKU: ".$product->getSku()."</info>");
                    $output->writeln("\t\t<info>Minimal Price: ".print_r($product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getAmount(),true)."</info>");
                    $output->writeln("\t\t<info>Core Session: ".print_r($this->_coreSession->getData(),true)."</info>");
                    $output->writeln("\t\t<comment>- - -</comment>");
                }
            }
            $this->_emulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation();
        }
    }
```

The problem is thet txtRates ara calculated only at the beginning, but i ned to refresh it every time after `$this->_coreSession->setCountryCode($locale['iso']);`
to get the corrects rates for each country.

In Magento 1.9 i used this:

```
            $locale = Mage::helper('ebaysync')->getLocale($site);
            Mage::reset();
            Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($locale['store']);
            Mage::app()->getStore()->setCurrentCurrencyCode($locale['currency']);
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setCountryCode($locale['iso']);
```

but i can't find any solution for Magento 2;

Any help?

Comment: Try to load your product collection adding a filter on storeId.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with cleaning the cache programmatically? That might work for you.  Just a suggestion. Because In magento 1 reset method used to warm up the magento cache. So you can give a try.

Comment: Tried to disable the cache, but taxes are calculated only when the script start